# What is IInAppBillingService.aidl in google in-app billing?

Tags: android, android-inapp-purchase

I don't know what is IInAppBillingService.aidl file in google in-app billing. is it java file or how it work in project. also main thing is how we can use this type file for other feature in android studio. and also want to know how it compile when we build apk. is any one know about .aidl file

Comment: It's a way to pass object between 2 process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know about aidl file you can check in detail here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Also if you want to clear about InAppBillingService.aidl, here it is:

`IInAppBillingService.aidl is an Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL) file that defines the interface to the In-app Billing Version 3 service. You will use this interface to make billing requests by invoking IPC method calls.`

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation,

```
IInAppBillingService.aidl is an Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL) file that defines the interface to the In-app Billing Version 3 service. You will use this interface to make billing requests by invoking IPC method calls.
```

More details here in this link http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-add-aidl

Answer (score 0):

InAppBillingService is the **service** that provides in-app billing version 3 and beyond.

This service provides the following features:

```
1. Provides a new API to get details of in-app items published for the app including
price, type, title and description.

2. The purchase flow is synchronous and purchase information is available immediately
 after it completes.

3. Purchase information of in-app purchases is maintained within the Google Play system
 till the purchase is consumed.

4. An API to consume a purchase of an inapp item. All purchases of one-time
 in-app items are consumable and thereafter can be purchased again.

5. An API to get current purchases of the user immediately. This will not contain any
 consumed purchases.
```